# Weighting in Stata when weight variable accounts for both sample-based and population-based corrections?

Tags: stata, survey

I am using National Survey Data (specifically, UK LCF) for Regression Analysis that contains a variable `weighta` described as following:

[image]

I really don't know which of the following Stata specifications for weighting is suitable to apply to my variable `weighta`. Can you please help me?

[image]

Here you can see how my the values for my `weighta` variable look like; they are not integer so this makes me doubt `fweight` specification in Stata would fit, but I am still not sure about any of the others.

`weightq=quarterly weights weighta=annual weights`

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the forum, @Linda! Generally, it helps with getting a response if you [provide some sample data](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/faq/how-can-i-input-a-small-dataset-quickly/) or a link to the dataset that people could use to answer your question.

Comment: Hi Mike! thank you for the tip! I will do that now :)

Comment: This question is better suited to Statalist or Cross Validated in my view.

Comment: Hi Nick! thank you! I will post it on Statalist too now :)

Comment: Linda, if you are are cross posting, can you provide a link to the cross post? This way, we can figure out whether you really still need help.

Comment: Of course! Sorry for that, I am new to the forum. Here the link to Statalist: https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1601431-weighting-in-stata-when-weight-variable-accounts-for-both-sample-based-and-population-based-corrections ; someone has already come to help :)